# What is $\int_0^0 \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$ and why?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$

What if we had $\operatorname{Si}(0)$?
I am very confused and have searched everywhere but cannot figure out the answer to this problem.

Comment: $\int_a^a=0$ by definition.

Comment: @zkutch what is the full definition? Do you know where I can find it written somewhere?

Comment: @zkutch I am not *necessarily* disagreeing with your comment.  However, I question whether (for example) $\int_0^0 \frac{1}{x} dx$ is *by definition* equal to zero, rather than is undefined.  **If** the latter, then this begs the question, and one must then notice that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is *finite* (i.e. $= 1$).

Comment: The function can be finite, but the integral of the function evaluated at a point is $0$

Comment: Intuitively, no dx fits between a and a, so the sum is empty. Check "riemann sum".

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan But what happens when you are evaluating the integral of a function evaluated in the interval [a,a], and the function is **infinite** at $(x=a)$, rather than finite?  This is what I am unsure of.  I attribute my lack of assurance to never confronting the combination of an improper integral that is undefined at a certain point with the integral of zero width whose lower and upper bounds are **that same** point.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3846089/evaluate-int-00-frac1xdx

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to “solve” the issue.

**Method 1.** We’re integrating the function
$$ \operatorname{sinc}x=\begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} & x\ne0 \\[6px] 1 & x=0 \end{cases} $$
but using a sloppy notation in the integral.

**Method 2.** We’re defining
$$\operatorname{Si}x=\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$$
for $x\ne0$ and extending the function by continuity with $\operatorname{Si}0=0$.

Both methods yield the same function, of course. In either case, something is left to the reader to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the integral is undefined because the integrand is undefined at $t=0$. You can fix by removing the singularity

$$f(t):=\begin{cases}1,&t=0\\\dfrac{\sin t}t,&t\ne0\end{cases}$$

and the integral is null.